# HTML: performance implications of pre-decoding images by displaying a clone of each image on the page before it is animated onto the screen

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance, animation

I am working on an application with a large number of animated images.
The main negative factor affecting frame rate is images being decoded while the animations are occurring.

To prevent this problem, I am inserting clones of images into the DOM, before they are expected to be animated into view. The clones have low opacity and tiny size in order to be visible enough to trigger decoding without affecting the page's appearance.

As revealed by chome's dev tools timeline, this effectively causes the images to be loaded from server and decoded in the client before they are animated, with positive effects on frame-rate.

I am trying to figure out if there may be adverse effects to this solution. For example, is there a risk of overloading the GPU memory limits for decoded images, and thereby slow rather than improve performance?

In the current implementation, the cloned images are constantly added and removed from the screen in anticipation of the user's expected viewing pattern of the content. If I could be certain that there is no harm in keeping more clones on the screen at once, the percentage of images that would be successfully pre-loaded and decoded would increase.

Comment: these sort of behind-the-curtain implementation details vary from browser to browser and even among versions. test around and see what works well, but don't spend a ton of time worrying about overloading or using some neat trick that might not work tomorrow or yesterday. that said, it sounds like what you're doing is fine, and works well.

Comment: Instead of playing with the DOM over and over, *(which is a slow operation since the browser may have to repaint all other elements on the page)*,  why don't you just preload the images into `new Image()` objects, kept in memory, I'm pretty sure your problem is not the decoding part, but the fetching one.

Comment: Decoding the images takes over 100 miliseconds. I am aiming for 16 milliseconds per frame. pre-fetching, as you stated, is simple and does not require inserting into the dom.  I am willing to take the relatively minor performance hit of adding more elements to the DOM because I do it while the page is idle and with absolute positioning to prevent re-flows.